# Docker nginx php in centos7 container

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm

I have to create a Dockerfile which has to inherit FROM centos:7 by definition and install nginx and php and get it to show a PHP file.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM centos:7
EXPOSE 80/tcp
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install epel-release
RUN yum -y install nginx php php-fpm
RUN echo '<?php phpinfo();' > /var/www/demo/index.php
```

**My problems:**

1. How can I make docker understand that nginy has to start when the container is created and started?
2. How do I make nginx understand to use PHP?

For 1. all I know is that this is not possible with *docker build*.

For 2. I wanted to use tutorials but those are all wrong, because:

- there is no `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory
- there is no file called `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` at any place to include in the nginx.conf

I have never worked with nginx before, so I have no idea where to start. No tutorial I found works, because all those files and folders don't exist. All I get is a 403 error page.

Comment: You're only supposed to run one thing in a container, thus you should have two containers, one for nginx and one for php-fpm. Both of these already have many containers on Docker Hub; look at how they are constructed for examples.

Comment: I know that this would be the better way. But in this case the Dockerfile HAS TO inherit from centos:7.

Comment: Again, you can use the existing container definitions as an example. See for example [centos/nginx-116-centos7](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/nginx-116-centos7) and [centos/php-73-centos7](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/php-73-centos7). Actually you probably should just stop what you're doing and use those directly.

Answer (score 0):

This the approach that I have you at some point, you have to install and to config the nginx on the *Dockerfile* and start it any time when you run the docker, set this on *docker-entrypoint.sh*

Dockerfile:

```
#Install and config Nginx
RUN {\
    apt-get install nginx -y\
    rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default\
    }

ADD YOUR_CONFIG_FILE /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
RUN service nginx start


RUN PATH="$PATH:docker-entrypoint.sh"
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

service nginx start
 
/bin/bash
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Docker doesn't allow me to start nginx because of "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted" even when the container is started with --privileged option. And how do I make nginx use PHP?

Comment: I just forget it now. Docker is not able to run PHP on nginx no matter what I tried. Even if nginx runs, PHP lets the container or even the whole machine crash.

Comment: What I use to do is create a bare docker container and install everything on it, try to make it work and after that I make the dockerfile, I don't know if that could help you to notice what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to keep the container alive by adding the following

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Hope it will help you and the other colleagues